# Cross compiling for arm64 on amd64 architecture

Tags: 64-bit, arm, cross-compilation, arm64

I trying compiling rpi-imager for arm64 and I have a problem.

```
dpkg --add-architecture arm64
apt update
```

Status of 'apt update' is OK, because I edited sources.list, where I'm changing from archive.ubuntu.com to ports.ubuntu.com

```
sudo apt install --no-install-recommends build-essential:arm64 devscripts:arm64 debhelper:arm64 cmake:arm64 git:arm64 libarchive-dev:arm64 libcurl4-openssl-dev:arm64 qtbase5-dev:arm64 qtbase5-dev-tools:arm64 qtdeclarative5-dev:arm64 libqt5svg5-dev:arm64 qttools5-dev:arm64 libssl-dev:arm64 qml-module-qtquick2:arm64 qml-module-qtquick-controls2:arm64 qml-module-qtquick-layouts:arm64 qml-module-qtquick-templates2:arm64 qml-module-qtquick-window2:arm64 qml-module-qtgraphicaleffects:arm64 make:arm64 dh-autoreconf:arm64
    Reading package lists... Done
    Building dependency tree... Done
    Reading state information... Done
    Note, selecting 'debhelper' instead of 'debhelper:arm64'
    Note, selecting 'dh-autoreconf' instead of 'dh-autoreconf:arm64'
    debhelper is already the newest version (13.6ubuntu1).
    dh-autoreconf is already the newest version (20).
    Some packages could not be installed. This may mean that you have
    requested an impossible situation or if you are using the unstable
    distribution that some required packages have not yet been created
    or been moved out of Incoming.
    The following information may help to resolve the situation:
    
    The following packages have unmet dependencies:
     debhelper : Depends: dh-strip-nondeterminism (>= 0.028~) but it is not going to be installed
                 Depends: po-debconf but it is not going to be installed
     devscripts:arm64 : Depends: libfile-dirlist-perl:arm64 but it is not installable
                        Depends: libfile-homedir-perl:arm64 but it is not installable
                        Depends: libfile-touch-perl:arm64 but it is not installable
                        Depends: libfile-which-perl:arm64 but it is not installable
                        Depends: libipc-run-perl:arm64
                        Depends: libmoo-perl:arm64 but it is not installable
                        Depends: libwww-perl:arm64
                        Depends: wdiff:arm64 but it is not going to be installed
     dh-autoreconf : Depends: autoconf but it is not going to be installed
                     Depends: automake but it is not going to be installed
                     Depends: libtool (>= 2.4.2) but it is not going to be installed
     dpkg-dev : Depends: make
                Depends: binutils but it is not installable
     perl-base : Conflicts: perl-base:arm64 but 5.34.0-3ubuntu1 is to be installed
     perl-base:arm64 : Conflicts: perl-base but 5.34.0-3ubuntu1 is to be installed
    E: Unable to correct problems, you have held broken packages.
```

Do you have any idea how to solve this problem.

Comment: I don't think you should be installing packages like `build-essential:arm64` at all - you should be using the native (i.e. amd64) cross compiler toolchain packages like [gcc-aarch64-linux-gnu](https://packages.ubuntu.com/jammy/gcc-aarch64-linux-gnu). See for example this introduction [Cross compiling for arm or aarch64 on Debian or Ubuntu](https://jensd.be/1126/linux/cross-compiling-for-arm-or-aarch64-on-debian-or-ubuntu)